# Process getRuntime taking a long time - Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, runtime.exec

I am working on a new application and I need to input some Shell command into android , however it seems that my command is taking quite a long time to start

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -m 10 -n 10");
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
 new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    //Parsing result to a StringBuffer
    (...)
 }
```

Almost half of the total time (34sec) is used to start the process , is it normal ? 
Is there a way to do something. This is in an Async Task , however for the first 17sec there is nothing display on the textView which is quite annoying ...

If you have any idea , just comment !

Answer (score 0):

`-n 10` means `update the display 10 times and then exit`. You don't need 10 updates, 1 is enough. Use this command instead and it should be much faster:

```
top -m 10 -n 1
```

Comment: Well , not really what I want in the end is a continuous output so the     `-n 10` is used to test the speed of the command , anyway when reading time taken line by line , first line took 18922 milisec and then only 185mili for other line therefore the problem is in the process building I think , but maybe this kind of delay is normal ?